# PHP: Header redirects me to previous instance of location page

Tags: php

I have a page that displays editing options if a certain POST variable is set, like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['manageType']) && ($_POST['manageType'] == 'edit'))
{   
    display_edit_gallery($title, $_GET['gallery']);
}
```

In display_edit, there's something like this:

```
<form action="manage/manage_gallery.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="gallery_page.php" />
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

I then do some stuff on manage_gallery.php and I finish with

```
header("Location: " . $_POST['page']);
exit();
```

The edit is performed, I am redirected, except it seems I'm redirected to the instance of gallery_page.php I just left. $_POST['manageType'] is still set (and so the editing options are still being displayed) despite the fact that nothing has been sent through post in manage_gallery.php. I do something similar with a 'delete image' option and the same happens. The image is deleted, but I need to reload the page for it not to be displayed anymore. It's like header() performs a 'back to the previous page' sort of thing.

I've used HTTP_REFERER instead and it works perfectly but I've been told it's not the safest option so I'd rahter avoid it . .

Comment: Nothing is outputted on the page the header is in. The form is displayed on the different page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
header("Location: " . $_POST['page']);
exit();
```

To:

```
echo <<<'EOD'
<script language="javascript">
window.history.go(-1);
</script>
EOD;
exit();
```

Comment: Where do you want the page to redirect to?

Comment: The page the user just came from which is why $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] would work, but isn't it not secure?

Comment: I've updated my answer to a solution that will work based on the additional information you have provided.

Comment: I don't think so but php security isn't my strong suit so I'd rahter be careful. If all else fails, I guess I could embed the header in a 'if(login_check()' clause (the edit could in theory only be performed by an admin on the site)

Comment: I've tried that before. It gives me a corrupted content error, I don't know why

Comment: If that is the case your only alternative is to use the solution I've just updated my comment to.

Comment: It's not working either. This is really bizarre, I can't figure it out

Comment: I see nothing. It doesn't do anything. I'm not being redirected, but there's no error. Does window.history.go() use cookies by any chance?

Comment: @downvoters why vote down? The answer is correct and is exactly what was asked for based on the criteria, it might not be the standard convention in performing a redirect but it works in the scenario given. Read the comments fully please.